# Check if char is existing in array

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

I am creating project in arduino.
In C. How can I check if return char is existing in my array?

This is how I want it.

```
char n[20];
char *adminName[] = {"Jane", "Joe", "James"};
```

I want to return `true` if `(n)` is in my list.

Comment: Here is [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071542/in-c-check-if-a-char-exists-in-a-char-array)

Comment: @captain Not really a duplicate of that post, since that post requests a blacklist of characters. There are likely a bunch of others that ask for this, though.

Answer (score 3):

Loop over array indices and use `strcmp(n, adminName[i]) == 0` to test whether the string `n` is part of the array.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the strcmp() that check the diff between 2 char *

```
char n[20];
char *adminName[] = {"Jane", "Joe", "James"};
int  i;

i = 0;
while (admminName[i])
 {
    if (strcmp(n, adminName[i]) == 0)
      return (true); 
    i++;
 }
return (false);
```

Comment: The adminName[] array does not have a NULL entry - your while loop will go past the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

There are many built in functions are there for this. why cant you use those functions rather than checking manually by loops?

Comment: There is a built-in function that searches for a string in an array of strings? Which one?

Comment: That sounds like Java or C++, there is no such function in C.