# Trying to make an if statement that checks if a text has ., ! or ? in it but it keeps giving errors

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

Here is my code: the function that gives me errors is `count_sentences`.

```
int count_letters(string text);
int count_words(string text);
int count_sentences(string text);

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    printf("%s\n", text);

    int letters = count_letters(text);
    printf("%i letters\n", letters);

    int words = count_words(text);
    printf("%i words\n", words);

    int sentences = count_sentences(text);
    printf("%i sentences\n", sentences);
}

int count_letters(string text)
{
    int letters = 0;

    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(text); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            letters++;
        }
    }
    return letters;
}

int count_words(string text)
{
    int words = 0;

    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(text); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ')
        {
            words++;
        }
    }
    return words + 1;
}

int count_sentences(string text)
{
    int sentences = 0;

    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(text); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == '.' || '!' || '?')
        {
            sentences++;
        }
    }
    return sentences;
}
```

Its giving me:

```
readability.c:66:28: error: use of logical '||' with constant operand [-Werror,-Wconstant- 
logical-operand]
        if (text[i] == '.' || '!' || '?')
                           ^  ~~~
readability.c:66:28: note: use '|' for a bitwise operation
        if (text[i] == '.' || '!' || '?')
                           ^~
                           |
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

Anyone know how to fix it? I know I can just make an `else if` block and get the same result but I would like to know if I could do it this way. it seems more effective and looks a lot nicer.

stackoverflow is giving me an error that is mostly code so ignore this please

Comment: The condition `text[i] == '.' || '!' || '?'` is really the same as `(text[i] == '.') || '!' || '?'` which is not what you want. I would assume that CS50 (which I guess you're using) would have had that information.

Comment: Said differently the syntactically correct way is `if ((text[i] == '.') || (text[i] == '!)' || (text[i] == '?')) ...`

Comment: This is a FAQ but the best duplicate I found is about relational operators and a bit far-fetched. Does anyone know of a better duplicate for this?

Comment: In addition to the options given, it may be a golden opportunity to learn about `switch` statements too.

Answer (score 3):

```c
if (text[i] == '.' || '!' || '?')
```

has the same meaning as

```
if (true)
```

That's because `text[i] == '.'` evaluates to either `true` or `false`, but both `'!'` and `'?'` evaluate to `true`, since their numeric value is not zero.

The correct test would be

```c
if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?')
```

or simpler, check the whole string with [`strpbrk`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk) which returns a pointer to the found `char` or `NULL` if none of the characters to search for is found:

```c
unsigned count_sentences(const char* text) {
    unsigned sentences = 0;
    for (; *text; ++text) {
        text = strpbrk(text, ".!?"); // search for any of '.', '!', '?'
        if (text == NULL) break;     // if none of the chars was found
        ++sentences;
    }
    return sentences;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c5hasEG6Y)

Answer (score 2):

The `||` operator compares two booleans and stops evaluating them as soon as one is true.
In your case, `text[i] == '.' || '!' || '?'`, this means:

1. evaluate `text[i] == '.'`. If true, stop and return true. Otherwise,
2. evaluate `'!'`. This is a constant character. Because it is not 0, it is always true. That's not the logic you want to express and the compiler detects that it is weird to test a constant variable. This is a warning because the program could compile like that. Good job on activating `-Werror` to detect this early!

What you want to do is keep comparing `text[i]` to other constants like that:
**`text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?'`**.

Since this is getting quite verbose and you might want to add other special characters later, you will want to use a more condensed syntax. Refer to this question for that: [In C - check if a char exists in a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071542/in-c-check-if-a-char-exists-in-a-char-array)